# Missing RAM after dual boot

Tags: windows-10, kali-linux, grub2, ramdisk

I have a Samsung NP350V5X-S01IN laptop with 4GB RAM installed.

I had windows 10 installed on my system. At that point windows task manager showed available RAM as **3.9GB**.

Then I installed Kali Linux to a different partition and used grub as the boot manager. At this point the available RAM according to windows task manager was only **2.9GB**. But both OS boots with no problem.

I then reinstalled windows 10 to the same partition as it was before. At this point grub broke and the system booted to Windows by default. Now the available RAM according to task manager was **3.9GB**

Then I repaired grub2. Now both OS loads with no problem. Now the task manager shows only **2.9GB** available RAM.

I checked the BIOS and it detects all **4GB** of RAM memory. Where is the missing **1GB** RAM? My Windows is not working at full performance due to this missing RAM. Please help me fix it.

Here is the current information from task manager itself.
**Memory

```
4.0 GB DDR3

Speed:  1600 MHz
Slots used: 1 of 4
Form factor:    SODIMM
Hardware reserved:  1.1 GB

Available   1.4 GB
Cached  1.4 GB
Committed   1.4/3.9 GB
Paged pool  187 MB
Non-paged pool  80.3 MB
In use (Compressed) 1.5 GB (0 MB)**
```

Here the hardware reserved memory is the problem. That **1.1 GB** memory is completely unusable.

Apart from this I have a dedicated 2GB Radeon 7670m graphics card too.

[image]

Should I unistall LINUX to recover this RAM. Any other ideas?

P.S

I have maximum memory box unchecked in Advanced boot options (some youtubers suggested this). And I see no option in my BIOS to manage this.

Comment: This is normal.  You arent missing any memory.

Comment: But I did have 3.9 GB RAM usable before installing Kali Linux

Comment: Is this a 32 or 64Bit Windows 10?

Comment: @magicandre1981 it is 64 bit. And I am sure it could not be the problem.